# Debug Assertion Failed: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block) possible free memory bug

Tags: c, pointers, debugging

I cannot wrap my mind around that problem. Program is working properly: Creates 4 txt files and fprintf sorted data there, but when I try to execute second free loop for second linked list it visual says:Debug Assertion Failed: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block). Could you help me?
Thanks in advance

It almost work properly but this exception is frustrating.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#pragma warning( disable : 6031 )
#pragma warning( disable : 4996 )

typedef struct pomiar {
    unsigned int nr_pomiaru;
    unsigned int nr_czujnika;
    char data_i_czas[20];
    double temp;
    struct pomiar* nast;
    struct pomiar* poprz;
}pomiar;

int main()
{
    printf("Nazwa pliku z danymi: ");
    char wejscie[40];
    scanf("%s", wejscie);
    FILE* input = fopen(wejscie, "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Nie udalo  sie otworzyc pliku z danymi\n");
        return 1;
    }

    pomiar* wsk = NULL, *glowa = NULL;
    while (!feof(input))
    {
        if (glowa == NULL)
        {
            glowa = wsk = malloc(sizeof(pomiar));
            if (wsk == NULL) 
            {
                printf("Blad alokacji pamieci\n");
                return 1;
            }
            wsk->poprz = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            wsk->nast = malloc(sizeof(pomiar));
            if (wsk->nast == NULL) 
            {
                printf("Blad alokacji pamieci\n");
                return 1;
            }
            wsk->nast->poprz = wsk;
            wsk = wsk->nast;
        }
        fscanf(input, "%d %d %s %lf", &wsk->nr_pomiaru, &wsk->nr_czujnika, wsk->data_i_czas, &wsk->temp);
        wsk->nast = NULL;
    }
    fclose(input);

    // dividing on for lists
    pomiar* glowa1 = NULL, * glowa2 = NULL, * glowa3 = NULL, * glowa4 = NULL;
    pomiar* wsk1 = NULL, * wsk2 = NULL, * wsk3 = NULL, * wsk4 = NULL;
    wsk = glowa;
    while (wsk != NULL)
    {
        if (wsk->nr_czujnika == 1)
        {
            if (glowa1 == NULL)
            {
                glowa1 = wsk1 = wsk;
                wsk->poprz = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                wsk1->nast = wsk;
                wsk->poprz = wsk1;
                wsk1 = wsk;
            }
        }
        else if (wsk->nr_czujnika == 2)
        {
            if (glowa2 == NULL)
            {
                glowa2 = wsk2 = wsk;
                wsk->poprz = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                wsk2->nast = wsk;
                wsk->poprz = wsk2;
                wsk2 = wsk;
            }
        }
        else if (wsk->nr_czujnika == 3)
        {
            if (glowa3 == NULL)
            {
                glowa3 = wsk3 = wsk;
                wsk->poprz = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                wsk3->nast = wsk;
                wsk->poprz = wsk3;
                wsk3 = wsk;
            }
        }
        else if (wsk->nr_czujnika == 4)
        {
            if (glowa4 == NULL)
            {
                glowa4 = wsk4 = wsk;
                wsk->poprz = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                wsk4->nast = wsk;
                wsk->poprz = wsk4;
                wsk4 = wsk;
            }
        }
        wsk = wsk->nast;
    }
    //highest and lowest temps and count of data for each sensor
    int ilosc1 = 0, ilosc2 = 0, ilosc3 = 0, ilosc4 = 0;
    double min1 = 1000, max1 = 0;
    double min2 = 1000, max2 = 0;
    double min3 = 1000, max3 = 0;
    double min4 = 1000, max4 = 0;

    pomiar* tmp = glowa1;
    while (tmp != NULL) 
    {
        ilosc1++;
        if (tmp->temp < min1) min1 = tmp->temp;
        if (tmp->temp > max1) max1 = tmp->temp;
        tmp = tmp->nast;
    }

    tmp = glowa2;
    while (tmp != NULL) 
    {
        ilosc2++;
        if (tmp->temp < min2) min2 = tmp->temp;
        if (tmp->temp > max2) max2 = tmp->temp;
        tmp = tmp->nast;
    }

    tmp = glowa3;
    while (tmp != NULL) 
    {
        ilosc3++;
        if (tmp->temp < min3) min3 = tmp->temp;
        if (tmp->temp > max3) max3 = tmp->temp;
        tmp = tmp->nast;
    }

    tmp = glowa4;
    while (tmp != NULL) 
    {
        ilosc4++;
        if (tmp->temp < min4) min4 = tmp->temp;
        if (tmp->temp > max4) max4 = tmp->temp;
        tmp = tmp->nast;
    }

    printf("Z pliku \"%s\" odczytano:\n", wejscie);
    printf("- z czujnika 1: %d pomiarow, temp. min = %lf, temp. max = %lf\n", ilosc1, min1, max1);
    printf("- z czujnika 2: %d pomiarow, temp. min = %lf, temp. max = %lf\n", ilosc2, min2, max2);
    printf("- z czujnika 3: %d pomiarow, temp. min = %lf, temp. max = %lf\n", ilosc3, min3, max3);
    printf("- z czujnika 4: %d pomiarow, temp. min = %lf, temp. max = %lf\n", ilosc4, min4, max4);

    //Saving to 4 files
    char wyjscie[40];
    printf("Podaj poczatek nazwy plikow do zapisu: ");
    scanf("%s", wyjscie);

    char wyjscie1[40];
    char wyjscie2[40];
    char wyjscie3[40];
    char wyjscie4[40];

    sprintf(wyjscie1, "%s%d.txt", wyjscie, 1);
    FILE* output1 = fopen(wyjscie1, "w"); // otwarcie pliku do zapisu
    if (output1 == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Nie udało się otworzyc pliku do zapisu\n");
        return 1;
    }
    tmp = glowa1;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(output1, "%i %i %s %lf\n", tmp->nr_pomiaru, tmp->nr_czujnika, tmp->data_i_czas, tmp->temp);
        tmp = tmp->nast;
    }
    fclose(output1);

    sprintf(wyjscie2, "%s%d.txt", wyjscie, 2);
    FILE* output2 = fopen(wyjscie2, "w"); // otwarcie pliku do zapisu
    if (output2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Nie udało się otworzyć pliku do zapisu\n");
        return 1;
    }
    tmp = glowa2;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(output2, "%i %i %s %lf\n", tmp->nr_pomiaru, tmp->nr_czujnika, tmp->data_i_czas, tmp->temp);
        tmp = tmp->nast;
    }
    fclose(output2);

    sprintf(wyjscie3, "%s%d.txt", wyjscie, 3);
    FILE* output3 = fopen(wyjscie3, "w"); // otwarcie pliku do zapisu
    if (output3 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Nie udało się otworzyć pliku do zapisu\n");
        return 1;
    }
    tmp = glowa3;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(output3, "%i %i %s %lf\n", tmp->nr_pomiaru, tmp->nr_czujnika, tmp->data_i_czas, tmp->temp);
        tmp = tmp->nast;
    }
    fclose(output3);

    sprintf(wyjscie4, "%s%d.txt", wyjscie, 4);
    FILE* output4 = fopen(wyjscie4, "w"); // otwarcie pliku do zapisu
    if (output4 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Nie udało się otworzyć pliku do zapisu\n");
        return 1;
    }
    tmp = glowa4;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(output4, "%i %i %s %lf\n", tmp->nr_pomiaru, tmp->nr_czujnika, tmp->data_i_czas, tmp->temp);
        tmp = tmp->nast;
    }
    fclose(output4);

    // Freeing memory!!!

    tmp = glowa1;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        glowa1 = glowa1->nast;
        free(tmp);
        tmp = glowa1;
    }

    tmp = glowa2;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        glowa2 = glowa2->nast;
        free(tmp);
        tmp = glowa2;
    }

    tmp = glowa3;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        glowa3 = glowa3->nast;
        free(tmp);
        tmp = glowa3;
    }

    tmp = glowa4;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        glowa4 = glowa4->nast;
        free(tmp);
        tmp = glowa4;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. That's a lot of code. Could you kindly provide a *minimal* reproducible example?

Comment: @Łukasz Mruczkowski Use English words for identifiers. Otherwise your code is unreadable.

Comment: This type of error *usually* means that you have written data after the end of memory you allocated - you have written data into memory that wasn't yours. Another possibility is that you free the same thing twice, or you freed something that you didn't allocate.

Comment: I think that when you divide the 1 list into 4, you don't end the 4 lists properly, so when you go to the end of glowa1, there can be list entries that are in glowa2 or glowa3 or glowa4.. The end of glowa1 doesn't have a null nast - it still points to whatever it pointed to when that node was in the big list. I could be wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong/26557243#26557243